# Advise needed: GameDev Course Outline

Tags: game-design

I plan to teach *"Introduction to Game Development"* to the CS undergrads next semester. Keeping in view the trends in 2022 what would be an ideal course outline or topics to teach to train the students so that they can create awesome games and also make some living as well?

Comment: Could you edit the question to include a bit more about their background and your course goals?  You've given a few hints, but an expansion would be very helpful.  Do you have a direction that you are already leaning?

Comment: `make some living as well`. Getting into game development is hard. Getting into [A listed game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_video_games_considered_the_best) development is even harder, probably more about who you know than what you know.

Comment: `would be an ideal course outline` Search other schools for their course outline and check the work the teachers do related to what they teach. Some just teach a class some are a focal point in the community and their cv shows it.

Comment: The [Unity Game Engine](https://unity.com/) was the go to software for teaching game design but IIRC they changed their pricing structure and it fell out of favor with college level teachers. You should verify that. However they have many resources related to what you seek, so much so that students may realize they can learn just as much for free on their own and not have to pay for a course.

Comment: I'm still itching to provide help here, though you're probably in the middle of your semester.  What is the background of the students?

Comment: What did you wind up doing?

Comment: @BenI. Well I was initially thinking of Unity but I have a thinkpad x220 so I am now leaning towards Harward's CS50 GameDev https://cs50.harvard.edu/games/2018/ . I think their approach is more towards teaching actual engineering while keeping the creation tools / engines as minimal as possible. What do you think ?

Comment: @GuyCoder Well I think there is also an educator plan. Check it out: https://unity.com/products/unity-education-grant-license. What do you think ?

Comment: @BenI. I chose Harward's GD 50  https://cs50.harvard.edu/games/2018/

Comment: @BenI. But now I need to see what kind of assignments or projects I can give along with this course.